# ERROR 1064 (42000) al importar una base de datos

Tags: sql-server

Estoy intentando de importar una base de datos pero no me deja me marca error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Procura que el código los comandos, los errores estén como texto. Replicar cosas que te pasan va a ser mucho más fácil para otros.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes. Recuerda responder a comentarios yendo a [edit] tu pregunta todas las veces que sea necesario.

Answer (score 0):

Estás usando backslash `\` para la ruta. Para el editor de comandos de mysql, ese carácter especial representa cosas especiales y por eso te dice que `\U` no se entiende.

Tienes que usar el comando `source` plasmando la ruta de otra forma. Con slashes, "como si trabajaras en linux"

`source D:/ruta/al/directorio/magico`